# Flask admin, a lot of records

Tags: flask, flask-admin

I need an advice about `flask-admin`.

I have a `Flask` application with a few entities:

- `A` – has a lot of records (about 1M)
- `B` – which has foreign key to `A`, at `field1`

By default `flask-admin` will create a view for `B` entity with a `<select>` tag for `field1`, and will try to load 1M records from entities `A` (huh).

I'd like to do something like `bootstrap select` with live search (that will use some some field to search from entities `A`). Anyway, I need to filter somehow selection to entities `A`.

So, how can I achieve it easily?

Answer (score 1):

Oh my inattention :(

This case described in [ModelView Configuration Attributes](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction/#modelview-configuration-attributes), `form_ajax_refs`.

So I need to declare this property in view for `B` entity

```py
class B_View(AbstractView):
    column_exclude_list = common_skip_fields
    form_excluded_columns = common_skip_fields

    form_ajax_refs = {
        'field1': {
            'fields': ['smth_field_to_search'],
            'page_size': 10
        }
    }
```